# Problem customize the height of column bar

Tags: amcharts4

The column bar is too small. And I couldn't adjust their height. The screen shot is attached here: https://prnt.sc/p09hj9.

I have tried all the methods of column series at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/columnseries/.

```
    am4core.ready(function() {

        // Create chart instance
        var chart = am4core.create("historical_monthly_chart_range", am4charts.XYChart);

        // Push data into the charts
        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis()); 
        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series.name = "Price Range";
        valueAxis.title.text = 'Price (S$ psf)';
        series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series.dataFields.openValueY = "min";
        series.dataFields.valueY = "max";
        series.tooltipText = "{date} \n Maximum: {max} \n Average: {average} \n Minimum: {min} \n Volume: {value}";

        // Setting the appearance
        series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
        series.tooltip.background.strokeOpacity = 0;
        series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
        series.tooltip.label.minWidth = 40;
        series.tooltip.label.minHeight = 40;
        series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "left";
        series.tooltip.label.textValign = "middle";
        series.fillOpacity = 0.5;
        series.tensionX = 0.8;
        series.fill = am4core.color("#697e69");

        var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series2.name = "Minimum Price";
        series2.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series2.dataFields.valueY = "min";
        series2.stroke = am4core.color("#697e69");
        series2.tensionX = 0.8;

        var series_average = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series_average.name = "Average Price";
        series_average.dataFields.valueY = "average";
        series_average.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        series_average.stroke = am4core.color("#000");

        /* Bar chart series */
        var barSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
        barSeries.dataFields.valueY = "value";
        barSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
        barSeries.fill = am4core.color("#000");
        barSeries.columns.width = am4core.percent(60);

        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

        chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bounty on this issue from AM charts however one workaround can be using scrollbar in Y axis like this following:

```
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

This is not the best solution i agree but you can use it to slightly zoom with the buttons and scale and see

let me know if it works!